# How to correctly define a multidimensional generalized Collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

For example, I want to create a map that is a map of a map of a map. So I have declared the map as so. From a resultset I want to create a JSON object.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>();
```

I could define as

```
Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

however I need to put items one at a time so I get the map I want and put it in. Then the same the following iterations so I would have to cast the object to the map which leaves unchecked warnings.

Is there a better way of declaration of this type of Collection?

Comment: It really depends what you want to do with the map - how you want to access the elements later.  You could consider using the Apache Commons class called `Triple`, to create something like `Map<Triple<String>, Object>`.

Comment: I probably should have clarified that I am trying to map a JSON object so would GSON be able to write that kind of map.

Comment: Is the number of nested maps dynamic, or do you know it in advance?

Comment: It is static right now but it may be dynamic later. So it would be nice if you told me both ways.

Comment: And what about the keys? Do you know them in advance, or are they completely dynamic? i.e. do you always have `key1: {...}, key2: {...}`, or could the JSON have whatever key?

Comment: Yes I know always know the keys. From a result set.

Comment: If you know the keys in advance, then create classes that mimic the structure of the JSON with attributes that have the same name as the keys.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Google Guava [MultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), but really you're better off creating a new Object and referencing the entire collection of data from the single key.

```
public class MyObjectData {

    private String string1;
    private Map<String, String> map;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

Then your map becomes `Map<String, MyObjectData>`

Comment: I don't think Guava's Multimap is suitable for OP. OP is asking about a map where the key returns another map. A Guava Multimap is not equivalent to nested maps. A Multimap is a map where the key returns multiple values.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: This only allows for one MyObjectData per key.

Comment: No you can still use Map<String, List<DataObj>> or Map<String, Map<String, DataObj>>. Depending on your needs it may or may not be better to encapsulate the logic in a separate class

Comment: Maybe you should have pointed OP to Guava's `Table`, which is exactly what OP needs. Well, maybe a table of tables of...